# How many different numbers can be found using 6 out of 8 digits $12345678$ beginning with $21$?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> How many different numbers can be found using $6$ out of $8$ digits $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$, if the numbers are not repeated but must begin with the digits $21$?

I'm getting 360. Am I correct?

$2,1,3,4,5,6 $

$$
6!/(6-4)!=360
$$

Comment: When you say "begin with $2$ and $1$", do you mean the first two digits have to be $21...$, or that the first digit has to be either $2$ or $1$?

Comment: The exact phrasing of the question is "begin with the digits 21." I assume it was an error, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I went ahead and changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct--it's the number of permutations of $4$ objects chosen from a set of $6$ ($3,4,5,6,7,8$).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you arrived at your formula, but I get the same answer.

The first two digits are fixed, so we only have to count the number of ways to fill up the remaining $4$ digits. We have $6$ digits to choose from (the digits $1$ through $8$, but not $1$ and $2$ because they've already been used up). So there are $6\choose4$ possible combinations of digits, but that doesn't take into account the differnet ways they can be ordered, so we multiply by $4!$ and indeed get the answer $360$.